# Jquery validationEngine and select2 using autocomplete fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript for the validationEngine plugin;

```
if(!$("#wizard_general_profile").validationEngine('validate')) return false;
```

This simply validates a wizard on my page, the problem is that it for some reason also validates the input field that select2 is using for auto_complete, but I only want it to validate on the select field.
Here is my html code;

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-3">Username:</div>
<div class="col-md-9"><select class="validate[required]" style="width:100%;" tabindex="" id="username_search" validate></select></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-row">
 <div class="col-md-3">Description:</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <textarea name="about" class="validate[required,minSize[5],maxSize[150]]"></textarea>
</div>
```

Ok so the textarea is working fine, and well the select field is also working fine.
But when you hit next it still gives a message that I have to insert a input field that is not really there, it only shows up when you click at the select so you can search for results.
Kind of hard to explain but I hope someone gets me.
Here a screen; http://puu.sh/6SEln.png